# Angular overlay (spinner) when we have multiple request

Tags: angularjs, spinner, overlay

I have below HTML panel and binds to the controller, in the controller I have 4 calls to server to get my data, my question is how can I show spinner or overlay on top of this panel until all the requests to the server are resolved and I can show the data smoothly.

```
<div class="container-fluid margin10 padding10 myPanel">
    <div class="row-fluid name" ng-bind-html="viewData.msg.name"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div ng-bind-html="'&bull; ' + (viewData.msg.filtersStr | limitTo: 140) + (viewData.msg.filtersStr.length > 140 ? '...' : '')" ng-attr-title="{{viewData.msg.filtersTooltipStr}}"></div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="row top-buffer-margin">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
            <div class="col-md-8"><span class="font10" translate="msgs.details.confidence"></span>:</div>
            <span ng-bind-html="viewData.msg.severity" ng-class="viewData.msg.severityColor" class="font10 col-md-4 confidence-span"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <table class="table-striped col-md-12 top-buffer-margin">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-3"></th>
            <th class="col-md-2 text-center" ng-bind-html="'<i>' + ('msgs.details.countColHead' | translate) + '<i>'"></th>
            <th class="col-md-4 text-center" ng-bind-html="'<i>' + ('msgs.details.dynamicCalculation' | translate) + '<i>'"></th>
            <th class="col-md-3 text-right" ng-bind-html="'<i>' + ('msgs.details.CalculationColHead' | translate) + '<i>'"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="col-md-3">                
                <div><span translate="msgs.details.number1"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <span ng-bind="viewData.msg.number1.dynamicCount "></span>               
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4 text-center" >
                <span ng-bind="viewData.msg.number1.dynamicCalculation "></span>

            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3 text-right"
                ng-bind="(viewData.msg.number1.percentageCalculation > 0 ? '+' : '') + viewData.msg.number1.percentageCalculation + '%'">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="col-md-3">                
                <div><span translate="msgs.details.number2"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <span ng-bind="viewData.msg.number2.dynamicCount "></span>                
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <span ng-bind="viewData.msg.number2.dynamicCalculation "></span>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3 text-right"
                ng-bind="(viewData.msg.number2.percentageCalculation > 0 ? '+' : '') + viewData.msg.number2.percentageCalculation + '%'">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="col-md-3">                
                <div><span translate="msgs.details.number3"></span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <span ng-bind="viewData.msg.number3.dynamicCount "></span>

            </td>
            <td class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <span ng-bind="viewData.msg.number3.dynamicCalculation "></span>               
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-3 text-right"
                ng-bind="(viewata.msg.number3.percentageCalculation > 0 ? '+' : '') + viewData.msg.number3.percentageCalculation + '%'">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>   
</div>
```

The controller is like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function myController($scope, BinsResource, msgEvents, appConstants) {

        var msg = null;
        $scope.viewData = {msg: {}};

        var init = function() {


        }


        var getMsgDetails = function() {


            msg = $scope.selectedMsg;
            //
            $scope.viewData.msg = {
                ruleName: msg.ruleName,
                date: moment.utc(msg.time).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                time: moment.utc(msg.time).format('HH:mm'),
                severity: msg.severity,
                severityColor: msgsService.getSeverityClassColor(msg.severity, appConstants),
                number1: buildEventsData(msg, appConstants.measureType.number1),
                number2: buildEventsData(msg, appConstants.measureType.number2),
                number3: buildEventsData(msg, appConstants.measureType.number3)         
            };

            var params = prepareDataForBinsHttp(msg);

            //number1
            BinsResource.post('number1', params).then(
                function(response) {

                    var calculationObject = calculateCalculation(response.data.Interval, msg);
                    $scope.viewData.msg.number1.dynamicCalculation = calculationObject.calculation;                    
                    $scope.viewData.msg.number1.dynamicCount = calculationObject.count;

                },
                function(error) {
                    //TODO : Display callback error
                }
            );

            //number2
            BinsResource.post('number2', params).then(
                function(response) {

                    var calculationObject = calculateCalculation(response.data.Interval, msg);
                    $scope.viewData.msg.number2.dynamicCalculation = calculationObject.calculation;                    
                    $scope.viewData.msg.number2.dynamicCount = calculationObject.count;
                },
                function(error) {
                    //TODO : Display callback error
                }
            );

            //number3
            BinsResource.post('number3', params).then(
                function(response) {
                    var calculationObject = calculateCalculation(response.data.Interval, msg);
                    $scope.viewData.msg.number3.dynamicCalculation = calculationObject.calculation;                    
                    $scope.viewData.msg.number3.dynamicCount = calculationObject.count;
                },
                function(error) {
                    //TODO : Display callback error
                }
            );

        }

        //
        $scope.subscribe(msgEvents.message._ALERT_ITEM_SELECTED_, function(selectedMsg){

            $scope.selectedMsg = selectedMsg;

            if(selectedMsg != null){
                getMsgDetails();
            }
        });

        init();
    };

})();
```

I want my HTML be blocked until getMsgDetails() does all its calls to server and calculation and was ready to populate the HTML, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option, is to use the following angular library

https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui

It will display a spinner, or a loading message, until all the promises are solved (it is configurable as well)

Demo here: 
http://angular-block-ui.nullest.com/#!/

Comment: I tried that component but it gave me this error after installing it with bower, Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: angular-block-ui/angular-block-ui.ng.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Comment: If its giving you that error is because the library is not property installed. Please check that the html template is accesible from you app. Check the file system, your dependencies in angular modules and so on.

Comment: Did you include the directive block-ui in your app html template?

Comment: Please if you find another solution, you should share it with the community... this is all about sharing information and constructing a knowledge base

Comment: mine is very specific solution that works only in my code and since its related to some business I can share all the details.